# getByElementId hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

```
document.getElementById(id).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

This is in my javascript file.

I'm trying to hide a div, which has the id of var 'id'.

The error console is listing that it isn't a function.

Edit:

I don't think I'm getting the right element this way (using `$("#" + id)`).

Let's say im making the div like this: `<div id="2">`, and the javascript function is getting 2

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById(id)` is Dom element. and it has no function `hide`

You have to use `$('#'+id).hide`. Or `$(document.getElementById(id)).hide`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#" + id).hide(...);
```

Don't use `getElementById` if you have jQuery.

Also, to fix your initial code, here's how it should have looked like:

```
$(document.getElementById(id)).hide(...);
```

This is because jQuery doesn't extend DOM elements, but it can "convert" them into jQuery elements (which have those cute functions) with `$()`.

Comment: Let's say im making the div like this: <div id="2">, and the javascript function is getting 2

Answer (score 2):

When using `document.getElementById(..)` you cannot use jQuery functions like `hide(..)`. Use the jQuery shorthand - `$("#" + id)`