# Why can't I find my div using a numeric id?

Tags: javascript

Edit: Sorry, a line got lost.

I'm making a div dynamically, which is

```
 <div id="102">
```

, with an inner class:

```
<a class="delete" onClick="del(102)">X</a>
```

In my javascript file, i'm trying to hide it with

```
$("#" + id).hide(2000)
```

But it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: You say div, but it's a link. Also it does not have an id... What should the value of "id" be anyway?

Comment: I can't see div in your code or any element with id.

Comment: Which error do you get ? Can you post the code creating the `<div>` ?

Comment: check firebug for errors or put this statement before hide, `if($("#" + id)){alert("exists")}` to check your div actually exists

Comment: since the code you have supplied is not sufficient to understand what you want,
people cannot really help you. you should give the correct code and explain yourself better.

Comment: @anu - `if($("#" + id).length>0){alert("exists")}`
otherwise it wont work.

Comment: By the way, there's no AJAX here at all.

Comment: Haven't you [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825940/getbyelementid-hide) it allready

Comment: if($("#" + id).length>0){alert("exists")} doesn't bring up the alert (whereas it does without the length>0)

Comment: @Nick - please read http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/check-if-an-element-exists-using-jquery/

Comment: Please stick a letter in front of your id... id="x102"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a numeric ID. Prepend letter(s) to it, like `div102`.

Specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you cannot start an HTML id attribute value with a number. This isn't actually officially noted in the specs (as far as I can fin), but does have many browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @Sohnee: Thanks. In fact it is stated in the specs: `id = name [CS]` and `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`. @downvoter: Could you please explain your reason for downvoting? Thanks.

Comment: you should supply a link cause I couldn't find it when I looked here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: @Sohnee: When you click `name` there, you get the naming rules. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: Great - links always help to add a bit of authority. If I could +1 the answer again I would!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code is, but this works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="102"><a class="delete" onClick="del(102)">X</a></div>');
});
function del(id){
    $("#" + id).hide(2000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CcBfs/

Comment: The program is calling from a SQL using ajax, and making divs for each message, with the message ID in the SQL table as the div id.
When the del(id) function is called, its (meant to) hide the div, and delete the sql (i am getting the sql delete fine).

Comment: also, there are different ids, not necessarily 102, which are made dynamically

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means. Reading your question, it says you are not getting the `$.hide()` function to work. The rest of the answer code is merely there to demonstrate it working.

Comment: And yes, technically you should not be using a numeric ID, although I'm not sure that matters for dynamically created content.

Answer (score 1):

this should work.
`onClick="$(this).parent().hide(2000);"`

Comment: what if the link is not the child of the target div?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#" + id).hide(2000)` will hide the element whose id is `id`
But `<a class="delete" onClick="del(102)">X</a>` doesn't have an id
have to say: really bad question

Comment: But also, `<a class="delete" onClick="del(102)">X</a>` is not a `div`.